# Even and Odd pseudo for this markup

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some HTML what will be in this format

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="birch">Testimonials</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 name">
            <p>Odd Name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-offset-1 col-md-11 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 quote">
                <p>Odd Quote</p>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 name">
            <p>Even Name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 quote">
                <p>Even Quote</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the odd names/quote to have slightly different CSS to the even ones. I tried this, however, it applies it to either both of them or none of them. Is this something I can do with CSS alone of would I need Javascript to achieve this?

```
.quote:nth-child(odd) {
    border-right:solid 5px #CCCCCC;
    border-left:none;
}

.name:nth-child(odd) {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: `nth-child` refers the the element compared with it's direct siblings. Neither `.quote` or `.name` have any siblings, so they will always be `n=1` (odd)

Comment: Can you add a class to all the odd ones and a different class to the even ones?

Comment: You can add even / odd classes on server side

Comment: I think I'll have to do it on the server side, I'd just have preferred to use CSS if it was possible

Comment: @oGeez It most certainly is possible with CSS. See my answer. Instead of selecting the children themselves, you select the odd rows, and then select those children. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by placing an `:nth-child(4n-2)` selector on the `.row` instead of its nested `div`. That would then select every 4th row after the 2nd row, which would happen to be the ones you want to be odd. In this case, the code would then be:

```
.row:nth-child(4n-2) .name {
    text-align:right;
}
.row:nth-child(4n-1) .quote {
    border-right:solid 5px #CCCCCC;
    border-left:none;
}
```

[**View demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NN3M8/)

That would select the `.name` element inside the 2nd, 6th, 10th, etc. row, and the `.quote` element inside the 3rd, 7th, 11th, etc. row of the table.

Comment: Thanks for that :), works great. However, I changed it to -4 and -3 as those styles looked better on even rows not odd ones :P.